# How to get world coordinate of a place by name or address

Tags: mapbox, geocoding

I want a function that the input is a string of name or address, and the output is the longitude and latitude.

Comment: What have you tried? Stackoverflow is not a code writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **Forward Geocoding**:

> Forward geocoding converts location text into geographic coordinates, turning 2 *Lincoln Memorial Circle NW* into *-77.050,38.889*.

https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#geocoding

Comment: Problem solved using https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/java/overview/geocoder/. I'm using Android. Thanks!